# why does the expression /0+[0-9]/ pass the test for "00f" ? "f" is a letter

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm learning rexExp and I have one like:

```
var str =/0+[0-9]/;
console.log(str.test("00f")) //outputs true when I wanted false
```

well I have been reading that `+` matches zero or more occurrences of the regular expression so there could be lots of *zeros*. In this example I only have *2* but the next character should be a *number*, (`[0-9]`), but in `00f` `f` is *not a number* so why is it passing the test?

If you can explain that, it would be great. If you can help me with what I was trying to work on originally that would also be great?

I'm trying to make a regular expression where the test should **fail** if there is a *zero in front of a digit*. There should be know letters in the string. `-0` should fail. Here are some examples:

```
004 should fail
00 should fail
04 should fail
4 should pass
400 should pass
0 should pass
-0 should fail
0ab00 should fail
0.004 should fail
```

Comment: Your pattern matches any zero with any number after it. Which is what `00f` contains...

Comment: What you want is `/^[1-9][0-9]*$/` or `/^[1-9]0*$/` (unclear what you want exactly). Your current regexp will match any `0` followed by exactly one digit (that may be `0`) thus passing `004`, `00`, etc. but failing on `4` and `400`.

Comment: just a side-note, `+` would match **1** ore more occurrences, not 0 ore more

Comment: It is funny how often the only problem is in (not) using anchors. Perhaps, the regex tag should include a note: **For a full string match, use *anchors** (`^`/`$` or `\A`/`\z`)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `test` would try to match the regex somewhere in the string. It doesn't need to match the entire string. In this case, the `0+` will match the first `0` and `[0-9]` will match the second `0`.

If you want to enforce full match, you should use anchors:

```
/^0+[0-9]$/
```

- `^` - beginning of the string
- `$` - end of the string

---

As for your main task - I'm not entirely sure if that is what is being asked for here, but I'll assume that there shouldn't be a sequence of digits that starts with `0` other than a `0` itself and `-0` is also unacceptable:

```
^(?!.*(\D|^)0\d)(?!.*-0).*
```

The idea is:

- `^` - from the start of the string
- `(?!)` - [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (fails the match if the pattern inside matches)
- `.*(\D|^)0\d` - after some amount of characters (`.*`), possibly zero, `(\D|^)` - after a non-digit character (`\D`) or (`|`) the start of the string (`^`), there is a `0`, followed by another digit (`\d`). We did that to make sure that this `0` is the first digit in the current number.
- `.*-0` - another condition for failure is if after some amount of characters (`.*`) we encounter `-0`
- `.*` - finally, match all the characters on that line if we the match didn't fail so far

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/vP6zO6/1)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I guess next time when I want multiple occurrences I'll use anchors  I just read that the `+` meant 1 or more occurrence so I thought it would work. It doesn't work in this case because the processor doesn't go through the entire string? it just finds the first occurrence The anchors make it go through the whole thing? something like that?

Comment: @jackblank, it will try to match the entire string. However, after it sees that it can't, in backtracks (drops the last matched character and tries again). This process is repeated until something is matched or there is nothing left to backtrack. However, with anchors it would fail instantly because if it ignores the last character after the match there isn't an *end of line* following.

Comment: question: when the `^` sign is inside bracket it means to negate. and when it is not it means beginning of the string. I see there are at least 2 meanings of the carrot. Am i correct?